# react-native: `this.state` is undefined in `render`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following code, which results in `this.state` being `undefined`:

articles.js

```
const React = require('react-native')
const _ = require('lodash')

const styles = require('../styles/articles')
const api = require('../data/api')

const {
  ListView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image
} = React

const Articles = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: () => {
    return { articles: [] }
  },

  componentDidMount: () => {
    const self = this
    const body = [{ screen_name: 'wired' }]
    api.get('timelines', body)
      .then(data => {
        self.setState({ articles : data })
      })
  },

  renderArticle: article => {
    const { container, thumbnail, rightContainer, title, year } = styles;

    return (
      <View key={article.id} style={container}>
        <Text style={title}>{article.title}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  },

  render: () => {
    console.log('render', this.state)
    const articles = _.map(this.state.articles, article => renderArticle(article), this)
    return <View style={styles.listView}>{articles}</View>
  }
})

module.exports = Articles
```

index.ios.js

```
const React = require('react-native')

const Articles = require('./src/components/articles')

React.AppRegistry.registerComponent('movies', () => Articles)
```

`console.log` in the `render` method says `this.state` is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using `React.createClass` with arrow functions, this messes up the binding to `this`.

So instead of doing

```
render () => {}
```

do

```
render: function () {}
```

or switch to ES6 classes, which would make your current class look like this

```
class Articles extends React.Component {
    renderArticles = () => {}
    render() {} // render and other lifecycle methods are always left without an arrow function
}
```

In ES6, React no longer supports the auto binding feature that `.createClass` provided for you which is why you want to use either and arrow function or use `.bind` when writing ES6 React components.

Also note that when using Babel, ES6 and React some features might be hidden behind stage flags, you'd have to investigate those as you go along!